# PendingIntent.getBroadcast lint warning

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

There is this new warning about using `PendingIntent.getBroadcast` as a notification's content intent:

```
builder.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(FirebaseNotification.this, newID,
                                                  new Intent(getString(R.string.notif_broadcast))
                                                          .setClass(FirebaseNotification.this, NotificationActions.class)
                                                          .putExtra(getString(R.string.thumbnail), bitmap);
```

Lint message:

> Notifications should only launch a BroadcastReceiver from notification
> actions (addAction)
>
> Notifications should only launch a BroadcastReceiver from notification
> actions (addAction) (This BroadcastReceiver intent is launched from a
> notification; this is discouraged except as notification actions)

I do not see this anywhere yet in the documentation, so why is this now discouraged? Is it for user experience and to provide clear context of what the notification can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wouldn't make much sense to a user if tapping a notification sent a broadcast. The expected behaviour would be to open the actual app that sent the notification originally, so I am not sure that sending another notification (which I presume is what your code achieves) would be good UX.

They do actually mention this is the [material design documentation](https://material.io/design/platform-guidance/android-notifications.html#behavior) where they say:

> When the user taps a notification, they should be taken to a screen in your app that relates directly to that notification and lets them take immediate action.

Comment: What I usually notice on other app is tapping the notification for example FB app, will open the relevant screen that pertains to what is in the notification title or description and that is what I am doing with the use of `getBroadcast` to open some activity using its package path.

Comment: Seems strange to do that when you could just use a normal intent to start your app with arguments/extras. Then you can use those to show the relevant UI. I don't think the method you're describing is very standard although it would accomplish the task, so if you need to use it, I would ignore the warning.

Comment: `setContentIntent` requires PendingIntent and I do not want to open any activity just when a the app received a notification out of nowhere thus I can't say using normal Intent is sufficient. Maybe I will just use it with addAction since doing that removes the lint warning.

Comment: Yes, you would use a `PendingIntent` with the [`PendingIntent.getActivity(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent#getActivity(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int)) method. Obviously you don't have to follow the guidelines or you could use an action like you said.

Comment: I just recall that NotificationAction.class here is a BroadcastReceiver used to handle many request or types of notification, and I am not technically opening a activity with the given code above. What it is going inside this BroadcastReceiver is opening a floating screen like a chat head.

Comment: I don't have any experience with floating screens like that, however out of interest, don't they still reside in an activity?

Comment: It does require service that has activity context but as I recall I can also show it even the app is not running or not minimize since the floating view was inside a Foreground Service and using WindowManager. I forgot this specific part since this is a bit old project I created last year.

Comment: The Suppress annotation is `LaunchActivityFromNotification` which is a little confusing description as it looks like you are not allowed to do that.

Comment: Ah I see! Yes that is confusing, I guess it's a *"you should launch an activity from a notification"* message.

Comment: I don't want to launch a complete activity with a layout and yada yada. I just want to launch an AlertDialog that does something on OK press. Is this not possible?

Comment: I don't really have enough information to answer that, I'd recommend posting a question with all the necessary details etc. if you've exhausted every option with search!